# A problem on order of intersection of two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the multiplicative group $S=\{z:|z|=1\}\subset \mathbb C$. Let G and H be subgroups of order  8 and 10 respectively. If n is the order of $G \cap H$ , then what is n ?

1. n=1
2. n=2
3. $3\leq n\leq 5$
4. $n\geq 6$

I am completely stuck on this problem ,please someone help me.Thanks.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem is definitely something you want to use here.

Comment: According to Lagrange theorem  ,it is 2 .am i right?

Comment: 2 or 1, it remains to show that $n\neq 1$...

Comment: If n=1,then order of G and H are relatively prime ,which is impossible. is it?

Comment: This is not the reason (two subgroups of a group might have the same cardinal but have a trivial intersection), using Lagrange's theorem the only conclusion you get is that $n$ divides both $8$ and $10$ whence divides $2=pgcd(8,10)$. The thing is that in $S$ you have exactly one subgroup of order $n$ which is the subgroup generated by some primitive $n$-root of the unity. You should use this to identify $G$ and $H$ and then find an explicit element which is in the intersection of both leading, indeed, to $n=2$...

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is a finite group with $n$ members and identity $1$ then $\forall x\in S (x^n=1)$ (Lagrange). So $x\in G\cap H\implies x^8=1=x^{10}\implies x^2=1\implies x\in \{-1,1\}.$ These implications are one-way. For the other direction we have $x\in G\iff x^8=1$ and $x\in H\iff x^{10}=1.$ So $G\cap H=\{-1,1\}.$

Comment: You mean $\{-1,1\}$ at the very end.